# How do I disable multithreaded calculation in Excel 2010 - as a permanent setting (without needing to set it on a worksheet)

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, multi-processor, multi-threaded

I need to be able to have excel 2010 open  (in windows 7 if it makes a difference) and have this setting defaulted to off.

I've tried unchecking the box and closing excel, saving the setting on the default book.xltx, logging off and back in deleting app data, etc....
help!

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to prevent Excel from using multiple CPUs at once, you could have Excel launch with affinity for only a single processor, for example with

```
start /affinity 1 "c:\path to office\excel.exe"
```

That would prevent Excel from using any CPUs but the first one.